# Brainfuck IDE for Windows

Tags: windows, ide

## Features

### Necessary

- Run in a single window (i.e. no toolbars in separate windows like in [Brainfuck Developer](http://4mhz.de/bfdev.html))
- Save to a file
- Execute programs inside the IDE
- Debug step through

### Optional (but nice)

- Syntax highlighting
- Compile to `.exe`
- Free
- Support for [multiple derivatives](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_extensions).

Comment: Debug step through = step-by-step execution?

Comment: Is it even possible to have syntax highlighting for BF? Wouldn't that just be different colors for each symbol?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs That's exactly what it would mean. Or possibly different colors for different functions, e.x. `<` and `>` would be the same color; `+` and `-` would be the same color; `[` and `]` would be the same color.

Comment: It's not really "production ready", but thanks for giving me some feature-requests to my [open source Brainfuck IDE - Brainduck](https://github.com/Zomis/Brainduck)

Comment: @SimonForsberg I wish I'd come up with that name.

Comment: @FracturedRetina slightly inspired by a project named [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck). Once the IDE is more functional (has most of the features you request), I will post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Visual brainfuck](https://sites.google.com/site/visualbf/):

- free
- Windows 7
- Run in a single window (i.e. no toolbars in separate windows)
- Save to a file
- Execute programs inside the IDE
- Debugger with step-by-step execution
- Compile to .exe

No syntax highlighting, no support for brainfuck derivatives.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Brainfuck Machine](http://www.kacper.kwapisz.eu/?i=19):

- free
- Windows
- Run in a single window (i.e. no toolbars in separate windows)
- Save to a file
- Execute programs inside the IDE
- Debugger with step-by-step execution
- Compile to .exe

No syntax highlighting, no support for brainfuck derivatives.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainduck](https://github.com/Zomis/Brainduck)

Download latest version on https://github.com/Zomis/Brainduck/releases

- Runs in a single window
- Can load and save to files
- Supports drag & drop of files into the IDE
- Execute programs inside the IDE
- Several options for debug step through:

  - Step by step
  - Run until next loop starts
  - "Step out" of current loop
  - "Step continue" which will go to the next iteration of the current loop, or to the end of it
- Some support for syntax highlighting
- Free, and open source!
- No support for derivatives, but does support embedding code with [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/)
- Support for some Groovy commands that allows you to mark memory cells with a name, and assert that you are on a specific cell. See [this Fibbonaci number generator](https://github.com/Zomis/Brainduck-BF/blob/d4f27673fcdfe06fc58e5d757ae847852326ac4b/fibonnaci.bf) as an example
- Supports analysis of your Brainfuck code:

  - Count the number of times your loops has been executed
  - Suggests simplification of code, for example `++>++<->` can become `+>++>`
  - Count the number of times your memory cells are being read or written
  - Memory to code mapping, and code to memory mapping

You want another feature? Create an issue in the Github repository, or submit a Pull Request :)